# How to reliable determine the current branch name of git submodules

Tags: git, bitbucket

**Background:**
As part of our build-script, we verify that all parts of a project are on an appropriate branch, and are tagged correctly.

We have been using `git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r"` to determine the branch name, but over time we've seen an increasing amount of falsely reported branch names.

I currently have a project where two of three submodules consistently are reported on wrong/invalid branches. :-(

All three submodules have been updated recently, going through the whole workflow, and are all on master now.
The main repository has had it's submodules updated, and have been tested on all stages of the workflow.

During the build the correct source if fetched, and the git tag (if set) can be verified. However, for some submodules the branch name returned are wrong or invalid. :-(

**Background update**: Partial fix; It turned out the invalid branch names were caused by a lack of branch history which in turn were due to a 'stuck' value in the ***advanced submodule*** settings of the ***[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) Git plugin***, whereby a shallow clone would always be performed on submodules. Updating the plugin fixed this part of the problem, so now branches are always returned, just not always the expected branch. (**Note**: Nothing in the question below has been updated to reflect this.)

**Workflow:**

- Feature -> Develop -> Master

**Versions:**

- Initially tested this with **git version 2.18.0.windows.1**
- Then upgraded to **git version 2.23.0.windows.1**
- The server site is running on BitBucket, and currently unknown version of git.

**Sofar I've tried the following:**

Ensure that the correct hash's are checked out: (Hash's are correct!)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "echo $name $sha1"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
submodules/basic ab7ce14cfaca960381f7c83bc1e6489c04863ce3
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
submodules/codecs f1329f063970448c5e06aa484df30d8d89683adc
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
submodules/scripts e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316
```

Verifying the logs:

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git log --oneline" (Hashes and Merge message are correct)
Entering 'submodules/basic'
ab7ce14 Merge pull request #53 in REF/basic from develop to master
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
f1329f0 Merge pull request #71 in PROT/codecs from develop to master
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
e0c2ceb Merge pull request #15 in CI/scripts from develop to master
```

The original method used to determine the branch name. (Branch name should be master)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/develop
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/develop
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Checking the remote server for merged hashes: (Returns nothing for the affected repositories)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r --merged $sha1"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Requesting the names revision of the hash   (--name-only makes for an easier parse-able output):  (Branch name appear to be undefined!?!)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git name-rev $sha1"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
ab7ce14cfaca960381f7c83bc1e6489c04863ce3 undefined
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
f1329f063970448c5e06aa484df30d8d89683adc undefined
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 master
```

Attempting to read the human readable object descriptor: (Returns truncated hash, instead of branch name)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git describe --always --all"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
ab7ce14
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
f1329f0
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
heads/master
```

Searching for the hash: (Returns nothing for the affected repositories)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch --contains $sha1"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
* (HEAD detached at ab7ce14)
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
* (HEAD detached at f1329f0)
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
* (HEAD detached at e0c2ceb)
  master
```

Searching on remote for the hash: (Returns nothing for the affected repositories.)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r --contains $sha1"
Entering 'submodules/basic'
* (HEAD detached at ab7ce14)
Entering 'submodules/codecs'
* (HEAD detached at f1329f0)
Entering 'submodules/scripts'
* (HEAD detached at e0c2ceb)
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

As suggested by @torek, I've also tested these commands: (Both provides nothing new for the affected submodules)

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git for-each-ref --contains=HEAD"
Entering 'Submodules/basic'
Entering 'Submodules/codec'
Entering 'Submodules/scripts'
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 commit refs/heads/master
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 commit refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 commit refs/remotes/origin/master

>git submodule foreach --recursive "git for-each-ref --contains=$sha1"
Entering 'Submodules/basic'
Entering 'Submodules/codec'
Entering 'Submodules/scripts'
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 commit refs/heads/master
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 commit refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
e0c2ceb9b792b45af46a91e3687acafeb0689316 commit refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I'm really struggling to understand the output. The hash values certainly are associated to a merge to master, but the various commands either returns nothing, unknown, a wrong branch (here develop) or a truncated (but correct) hash.

For all of this, it should be noted that teh BitBucket GUI shows everything correct, I just expected to be able to do the same with CLI commands.

How do I proceed from here?

How do I ensure to get a reliable and correct result?

Comment: Submodules are normally not on *any* branch; and in any case, regardless of whether or not a submodule has a current branch, its branch is quite irrelevant to the superproject, which records only the hash ID. A later clone of the superproject followed by a request to synchronize its submodules uses the hash IDs that the superproject has recorded in the commit checked out in the superproject, so that the names, if any, in any of the submodules, become irrelevant again.

Comment: That said, each submodule *is* a Git repository, so each one *does* have a `HEAD`. While it's normally detached (hence no branch), you *can* enter the submodule and do any Git operation there that you like. That's exactly what `git submodule foreach` does: it runs some arbitrary shell command inside the Git repository that holds each submodule. But since the superproject records raw hash IDs, what you find with a submodule's `git branch` command is unimportant. The only thing that matters to the superproject is the hash ID you find by running `git rev-parse HEAD`.

Comment: @torek Thank you. I don't see any reason why a subproject should not follow the normal workflow - in this case, at least, it does. I agree that the superproject only records the hash of the subproject, regardless of the branch it's on, however this should not limit the ability to read the branch name by using the hash to look it up.

Comment: Hashes do not uniquely define branch names. Branch names map to hashes, not the other way around. Two branch names can have the same hash ID. Other than that, and the fact that the superproject doesn't *use* branch names, there's no reason you can't look at the branch names ... but they just don't *matter*, at least not to the superproject. (Since the submodule is a Git repository that can be unaware of the superproject, you *can* enter the submodule and just use it, and then branches mean just what they always mean.)

Comment: @torek I normally expect at least one branch to exist for a given hash - especially when a commit/merge has been made to said branch. What I don't understand is why this name sometimes is blank, unknown, wrong (as in none of the found branches match the branch the commit were made to) or just return the truncated hash.

Comment: If some commit is in *no* branches (`git branch --contains <hash>` produces nothing), it needs to be protected by something else: e.g., it may be contained within the series of commits that ends at some *tagged* commit, or it might be protected by a remote-tracking name or a `git stash` commit-set. This is all normal, or reasonably close to normal, even in a non-submodule repository. The only true name for a commit is its hash ID, so that's what superprojects record.

Comment: @torek So do you know a way to determine what protects this a specific hash? This could perhaps this could provide clues to track down the branch name.

Comment: If your Git is reasonably modern, `git for-each-ref` will have a `--contains` option: `git for-each-ref --contains=HEAD` will find any refs that retain the hash ID. If it prints nothing, then someone has made a commit at a detached HEAD (because HEAD itself counts as well, though for-each-ref skips it). In this case *only* `HEAD` itself protects the commit, and moving to a branch puts the commit in danger of being cleaned-up by the garbage collection process (though the `HEAD` reflog will retain it for a month anyway).

Comment: Note that in this case, it means someone went into the submodule and made *new* commits there without thinking about the fact that the submodule is a submodule (a slave of the superproject). Submodules are not designed to be updated on their own like this. Think of a submodule as "I've borrowed Bob's project". To update it, you work with Bob to update *his* project first, as it were. Now Bob has the new commit in *Bob*'s `master`, and you can bring the new commit into your local submodule, check it out, and then make a superproject commit that uses it by hash ID.

Comment: @torek I know for sure that the last merges to develop and to master were performed ensuring that it's two separate projects, but I'm not entirely sure if the original feature were. Will have to investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out that the Jenkins Git Plugin were playing tricks with me, only the  problem with wrong branch names remained. This turned out to be the dynamical nature of git, and a misunderstanding on how the command `git branch -r` actually worked.

The git branch documentation states:
`git branch` default operation is `--show-current`.
`--show-current`, Print the name of the current branch. In detached HEAD state, nothing is printed.
`-r` List or delete (if used with -d) the remote-tracking branches.

The **current branch** mentioned above, is not the current branch that has been checked out locally, but rather the checked out branch's remote current HEAD. So all the development that has occurred following the time of the branch are included in the output, such as:

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r"
Entering 'Submodules/basic'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/bugfix/something1_after_the merge
  origin/develop
  origin/feature/something2_after_the merge
  origin/feature/something3_after_the merge
  origin/master
Entering 'Submodules/codec'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/develop
  origin/feature/something4_after_the merge
  origin/master
Entering 'scripts'
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/feature/something5_after_the merge
  origin/develop
  origin/master
```

To ensure that we get the output only directly including the version of out local branch, we need to add the `--contains` option, providing the sha1. Additionally, by sorting for the reverse commit date, using `--sort=-committerdate`, we further ensure that the exact branch name used for the commit to will be first in the output:

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r --sort=-committerdate --contains $sha1"
Entering 'Submodules/basic'
  origin/master
Entering 'Submodules/codec'
  origin/master
Entering 'Submodules/scripts'
  origin/master
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

With this, I get the output I were expecting.

**Bonus:**

To solely get the branch name of the checked out hash, and nothing more, the following can be used. It only operates on the first line, and strips anything before and including the `origin/` branch name:

```
>git submodule foreach --recursive "git branch -r --sort=-committerdate --contains $sha1 | while read line ; do line=${line#*> }; line=${line/#origin\/}; echo line; break; done;"
Entering 'Submodules/basic'
  master
Entering 'Submodules/codec'
  master
Entering 'Submodules/scripts'
  master
```